# Automate email send on build failure - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new in Jenkins. We have configured Jenkins to build our projects (we have more than 30 projects) and now we are looking for a solution to send emails on build failure. 
We have found a solution to do it, modifying the Jenkins file of each project and executing the following code on build failure.

```
 emailext (
  subject: subject,
  body: details,
  recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

However, this will need a lot of maintaining time.

Is there any way/plugin to configure the email functionality centrally for all the pipelines/jobs? If yes can you give us more details?

Thank you in advance.

---

### How we solved the problem

Hey. To solve the issue we decided to create a Global Pipeline Library. 
This library is loaded in every Jenkins file using the following line.

> @Library('JenkinsPipelineLib') _

Every time a build fails, the method from the library is called and the emails are sent. Thus, all the functionality is kept in a single file! 
It's not what we had in mind at the beginning but it works :)

Thank you

Comment: Hi, probably [Configuration Slicing](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) is what are you looking for, then also [mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) or similar, and you should to be able bulk config in configuration slicing in the jenkins administration

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I will have a look at it and let you know!

Comment: We are also using [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin),  plugin but I think the first one should be relevant, it adds the mail step to the post build actions, so in the slicing, you can "bulk way" configure this part for each job, but I am only not sure, if it will be also possible for pipeline jobs, probably not in this case. But you can try

Comment: If it will dont be possible to configure per pipelines as well, also I got an idea to create some job only for notification, and then (probably again with some plugin or manually) trigger it from the specific jobs, it should also leads to requested

Comment: That may be a good idea too..! Thanks!